# OpenDj as backend and accessing through REST API doubts

Tags: rest, openam, opendj

I'm doing a project using Open Am and OpenDJ as backend, I'm directly calling OpenDJ REST API for profile adding and Editing, I have the following doubts.

Is it possible to store JSON in to the OpenDj  field?
Any size limitation to fields in OpenDj  ?
Any change tracking option in OpenDj/Open AM ?
can Ido an Upsert (update if existing or Insert if it is new) through REST API?
can I add around 500 fields to a single profile? Any limitation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to store JSON in to the OpenDj field?

You can store JSON in an attribute, however you should be aware about the format... (non ASCII values must be Base64 encoded before being stored).

> Any size limitation to fields in OpenDj ?

Depending on the "syntax" (type) defined for a given attribute, there could be a limitation.

> Any change tracking option in OpenDj/Open AM ?

OpenDJ audit log can be enabled to show change in LDIF format; see OpenDJ docs. OpenAM only consumes identity information from configured data stores.

> can Ido an Upsert (update if existing or Insert if it is new) through REST API?

Yes, see https://backstage.forgerock.com/#!/docs/opendj/2.6.0/admin-guide/chap-rest-operations#update-rest

> can I add around 500 fields to a single profile?

Yes, 'field' is called an attribute in LDAP world.

> Any limitation?

apart from disk space and memory, not really

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comments. Could you please send some links which is more helpful to Know OpenDJ LDAP Commands.

Comment: it depends what you are looking for a general starter is (drafts for upcoming release) http://opendj.forgerock.org/docs.html

There you also have links for the docs of released versions.

Comment: You may check OpenAM mailing list archive (http://lists.forgerock.org/pipermail/openam/)